# XeLaTeX renders broken text after upgrade to Ubuntu Vivid

Tags: fonts, ubuntu

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu Vivid, which broke the XeLaTeX rendering on my system. Only `\textbf{}` and `\textit{}` of specific fonts are affected. The character table seems to be off-by-one. I use TeXworks.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Nimbus Roman No9 L}

\begin{document}
ABC \textbf{DEF} \textit{GHI}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image: bad rendering]

The XeTeX version is 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.4.27).

This is the file list I got after I enabled file list logging:

```
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2014/09/15 v5423 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2014/09/15 v5423 L3 programming layer 
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3unicode-data.def    2014/08/12 v5276 L3 Unicode data
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
  xparse.sty    2014/09/15 v5423 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many other characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2014/07/25 v4.03 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)
fontspec.cfg
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
```

Carrying out a font trace (setting `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` in the source and executing `xelatex --no-pdf file` and `xdvipdfmx -vv file.xdv`) gives

```
Requested font "Nimbus Roman No9 L/B/OT:mapping=tex-text;mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt -> /usr/share/fonts/type1/texlive-fonts-recommended/utmb8a.pfb
```

from XeTeX and

```
pdf_font>> Type0 font "/usr/share/fonts/type1/texlive-fonts-recommended/utmb8a.pfb" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=</usr/share/fonts/type1/texlive-fonts-recommended/utmb8a.pfb/0/H/65536/0‌​/0,1>..
```

from `xdvipdfmx`.

What is going on?
How can I fix this?

Comment: This could indicate that there are two versions of a font in your system. Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts= 1` to your document. Then compile on the terminal in two steps; `xelatex --no-pdf file`  and `xdvipdfmx -vv file.xdv` and compare the pathes in the .log-file with the pathes in the output of xdvipdfmx.

Comment: I updated the question to include the file list and XeTeX version. I also compared the paths: the .log file contains for example `Requested font "Nimbus Roman No9 L/B/OT:mapping=tex-text;mapping=tex-text;" at 
10.0pt
 -> /usr/share/fonts/type1/texlive-fonts-recommended/utmb8a.pfb` while the output of xdvipdfmx has `pdf_font>> Type0 font "/usr/share/fonts/type1/texlive-fonts-recommended/utmb8a.pfb" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=</usr/share/fonts/type1/texlive-fonts-recommended/utmb8a.pfb/0/H/65536/0/0,1>.`. That looks okay to me, right?

Comment: Do you really have texlive 2015? Then your version of fontspec looks too old. Mine has a date of 2015/03/14 v2.4c. Is user/share the normal location for texlive fonts in ubuntu?

Comment: According to my package manager, my texlive version is 2014.20141024-2ubuntu1, but according to the first line in the .log file: '(TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian)'. Maybe this version discrepancy is part of the problem?